# Multi file upload with ajax along with a form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I need to design a form with several text field and several file to be uploaded along with the form. I would like to use ajax to to submit it, and i was thinking about using a jquery plugin to show a progress bar.(I am using php server side)

The problem is that if i use something like that, the upload start asyncronously, but i want to really upload the files only when the whole form is validated and submitted.

Is there a way to pre-upload the files showing the progress bars, but to really save them on form submit? What happens if the user pre-upload the files then closes the form?

Comment: "a jquery plugin" -- please clarify which one

Comment: I was thinking jquery file upload, but if there is something better feel free to suggest. http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two statements are incongruous:

> > "i want to really upload the files only when the whole form is validated and submitted."
> >
> > "...pre-upload the files showing the progress bars, but to really save them on form submit"

If you want to upload the files in the background but only save them once the form is submitted, do something like this:

- Upload in the background to a "holding" directory
- When the user submits the form, move the files from the "holding" directory into the real storage directory
- Periodically delete any files in the "holding" director that are older than X hours